# Macro similar to section with label/reference and custom format

Tags: macros, sectioning, labels

I am trying to write a macro (\exhibitTitle) that would behave similar to section/chapter, but with its own counter that increases by 1.
Its important that it supports label (doesn't have to be standart \label or \ref).

For example \exhibitTitle{First Exhibit} should output 
'First Exhibit + counter number'
in bold in the center of line (like \exhibitTitle is defined in the example below).

\ref{exhibit1} (or any other reference macro name) should output integer count that corresponds to label exhibit1.
Count should start from 1 and increases by 1 every time \exhibitTitle{...} is used (and only if \exhibitTitle), that is this counter shouldn't be affected by \section.

\exhibitTitle{text} will be in the very end of the document (after all references to Exhibit labels in text).

Basically labels should work in very similar way as with section/chapter.
Current \exhibitTitle in code below does automatic numbering, but I don't see how to add label support to it.

Minimal example (doesn't work b/c I don't know how to do this):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\newcounter{exhibitcounter}
\newcommand{\exhibitTitle}[1]{
\stepcounter{exhibitcounter}
\begin{center}
\begin{Huge}
Exhibit \arabic{exhibitcounter} \end{Huge} \\ #1
\end{center}
}
\begin{document}
Text text Exhibit \ref{exhibit1}
Text text Exhibit \ref{exhibit2}
\exhibitTitle{First Exhibit} \label{exhibit1}
\exhibitTitle{Second Exhibit} \label{exhibit2}
\end{document}
```

Thank you

Comment: change `\stepcounter` to `\refstepcounter` and then `\label` will work (and add `%` to ends of lines in the definition)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You did not commented on `Huge` as an environment. I thought we were supposed to say `\Huge` instead.

Comment: @Denis it's usually good style to do so (and it only works correctly here due to the trailing `\\ ` which are normally to be avoided, but by design in latex any declaration can be used as an environment. (the latex book gives the example of using `\begin{em}` instead of `\em` for example)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Quite clarifying. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you! Will try.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Still not sure about your last comment about Huge... Is it better/safer to use \Huge or \begin{Huge} \end{Huge}?

Comment: normally better to use `\Huge`, but `\begin{Huge}...\end{Huge}` is the same as `{\Huge...}` so normally (in either case) you need a blank line at the end of `...` but here it is in the scope of `\centering` which makes `\\ ` be `\par` so equivalent to a blank line so the trailing `\\ ` is enough.